# Configuring a jshint task in vscode and understanding problemMatcher

Tags: jshint, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to integrate jshint with vscode. The jshint task runs and correctly displays the outcome in the output panel but nothing else and it terminates immediately. Here is the task definition.

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command":  "jshint",
  "args": ["${file}"],
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "isWatching": true,
  "problemMatcher": "$jshint",
  "showOutput": "always"
}
```

**Question**: What are the purpose of the `isWatching` and `problemMatcher` flags? I would have thought `isWatching` would relaunch the task on every save or every change and that `problemMatcher` would take the output and integrate with the editor errors and warnings. The documentation is not clear to me so I would appreciate guidance on the purpose of these flags and on integrating a linter with vscode.

Comment: mhm, where did you get the task defnition from? Found anywhere or written by yourself? Thanks!

Comment: @malte. It was patched together after many trial and errors. I later found out by re-reading the documentation that an absolute path is required. I dropped the whole idea since "isWatching" was not supported, the lint task has to be triggered manually, and the error output is not integrated with the editor. I have learned to live with the build-in linter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of isWatching is to support task that watch the file system (e.g. like gulp.watch). However the watching support has still some limitations which we are working on. That is why we never announced it (e.g. is not part of the doc https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks).

For a description of the problemMatcher property please have a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher

Comment: Thanks. I have already looked at the problemMatcher section but can't figure out why there is a predefined `$jshint` that does not work with *jshint*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK. But I grabbed this from one of your samples and `isWatching` is in there.   https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript

Comment: Problem matchers just look like they handle messages from console output.  From what i can tell reading the documentation, they don't interact with the build process in any way.  Am i wrong?

Comment: @DirkBäumer where can the definition of the `$jshint` problem matcher be found? How would anyone know that `$jshint` is even a thing

Answer (score 0):

I have set jshint in vs code on Ubuntu 16.04.3 by following steps:
1.install jshint globaly so you can use anywhere by using command:
`npm install -g jshint`
2.Now open vs code and go to **extensions** and search for *jshint by dirk* and install this.
3. Now go to **File > Preferences > settings** 
   here in user settings add these line as shown in image
    [vs code user settings snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srKyR.png)
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srKyR.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ysC9.png    save and restart

3.more setting options can be found in **> extension> installed extensions > jshint** . Here on clicking jshints contributions tab you can find [more options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srKyR.png) which you can add to your user settings for vs code.

For more info use these links :

- http://avillenas.com/post/installing-jshint-and-jscs-in-visual-studio-code
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-jshint
- http://jshint.com/install/